# Find a value in JsonArray Object using contains keyword in jsonpath

Tags: arrays, json, json-path-expression

In below JSON, I need get "fieldValue" only if "fieldName" contains 'mobile'.

```
{
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "personal info",
      "fieldValue": "something"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "private info",
      "fieldValue": "nothing"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "mobile/personal number",
      "fieldValue": "00000000000"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "official number",
      "fieldValue": "1111111111111"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: Above Json is a sample one it doesn't contain actual values.

I also tried `$.fields[?(@.fieldName =~ /mobile.*?/)].fieldValue`
But it is returning whole list, Here mobile will come any place not only as prefix, I need to check if the fieldName contains 'mobile' then fieldValue should return.